# I'm trying to calculate trailing 6 month, 1 year, 3 year, and 5 year order sums and it's not summing up correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to calculate trailing 6 month, 1 year, 3 year, and 5 year order sums for the ITEM id and it's not summing up correctly. I'm expecting 20 total orders in Trailing 6 month and 1 year and I'm getting 2. What is wrong with my code?

Here is my code with a sample df:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ITEM': [1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001],
    'ORDDATELINE': ['2/22/2021  2:53:00 PM', '2/26/2021  1:13:00 PM', '7/30/2021  1:49:00 PM', '11/21/2022  9:00:00 AM', '2/1/2021  5:48:00 AM', '1/27/2022  12:11:00 PM'],
    'ORDQTY': [15, 10, 30, 2, 5, 18],
})

# Convert date string to datetime format
df['ORDDATELINE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ORDDATELINE'])

# Define date ranges for trailing calculations
six_months_ago = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=180)
one_year_ago = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=365)
three_years_ago = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=3*365)
five_years_ago = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=5*365)

# Calculate trailing sums
trailing_6_months_sum = df.loc[df['ORDDATELINE'] > six_months_ago].groupby(['ITEM', 'ORDDATELINE'])['ORDQTY'].sum().groupby('ITEM').sum()
trailing_1_year_sum = df.loc[df['ORDDATELINE'] > one_year_ago].groupby(['ITEM', 'ORDDATELINE'])['ORDQTY'].sum().groupby('ITEM').sum()
trailing_3_years_sum = df.loc[df['ORDDATELINE'] > three_years_ago].groupby('ITEM')['ORDQTY'].sum()
trailing_5_years_sum = df.loc[df['ORDDATELINE'] > five_years_ago].groupby('ITEM')['ORDQTY'].sum()

# Combine trailing sums into a single DataFrame
result_df = pd.concat([trailing_6_months_sum, trailing_1_year_sum, trailing_3_years_sum, trailing_5_years_sum], axis=1)

# Rename columns
result_df.columns = ['Trailing 6 Months', 'Trailing 1 Year', 'Trailing 3 Years', 'Trailing 5 Years']

# Fill NaN values with 0
result_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Reset index to include ITEM as a column
result_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(result_df)
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
   ITEM  Trailing 6 Months  Trailing 1 Year  Trailing 3 Years  Trailing 5 Years
0  1001                  2                2                80                80
```

This is what I should be getting:

```
   ITEM  Trailing 6 Months  Trailing 1 Year  Trailing 3 Years  Trailing 5 Years
0  1001                 20               20                80                80
```

I've tried group by both ITEM and ORDDATELINE in order to sum the quantities for each individual order and using >=, so I'm not excluding orders that occurred exactly six months ago or one year ago.

I don't know what is wrong with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you expect "20 total orders in Trailing 6 month and 1 year" when there is only one date within the past year of today and it only has two orders? `3 1001 2022-11-21 09:00:00 2`

Comment: As far as I can tell the code is correct and getting the right dates. Are you sure you want to use the current date and time?

Comment: You can try to get the cumulative frequency by doing `df.set_index('ORDDATELINE')['ORDQTY'].cumsum()` and apply your conditions from there, it would be much easier.